# Discord JDA Bot doesn´t respond on slash Command-

Tags: java, discord-jda

my Discord Bot doesn´t respond on my slash Command messages. May you can help me. Here is my code:
main class

```java
public class dcbot1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException, InterruptedException {

        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("TOKEN")
                .setActivity(Activity.listening("Testen"))
                .addEventListeners(new TestSlashCommand())
                .build().awaitReady();

        Guild guild = jda.getGuildById("GUILDID");

        if (guild != null) {
            guild.upsertCommand("test", "Testet den ersten SlashCommand").queue();
        }
    }
}
```

and the Command class:

```java
public class TestSlashCommand extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onSlashCommand(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
        if(event.getName().equals("test")) {
            event.reply("Drücke die Knöpfe zum ausprobieren!").queue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't override the method from `ListenerAdapter` correctly. It is called `onSlashCommandInteraction` and not `onSlashCommand`.

Comment: Oh thanks, I missed that in the tutorial